# Winforms C#: Scrolling changes location of my buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, location

I'm working on a project on winforms, and I recently realized that if I scroll down then cause another button to appear, it appears in a different location than I meant. I need to know how to fix that, I mean how to make it so that the button appears in a location on the entire form.

I have two buttons, one makes the other appear
Here is an example of a code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AutoScroll = true;
    this.Controls.Remove(button2);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button2.Dock = DockStyle.None;
    this.button2.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
    this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(110, 96);
    this.Controls.Add(button2);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(button2);
}
```

It does not work.

Comment: Check out the Anchor property on the button.

Comment: it needs to be in a very specific place

Comment: I understand that, but what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried doing the anchor and the dock, like I said before, it doesn't work

Comment: Then you need to provide more information, and maybe a screenshot of your UI in this case. We do not know what your UI look like.

Comment: It won't let me add a picture, reputation too low

Answer (score 0):

As scheien has suggested, set the location of the button where you want and set the Anchor property to desired values (Left, Top, Right, Bottom). This will fix the location of the button relative to the edges of the form selected.

If you mean you don't want the button to move even when the user scrolls and reads maybe some text, put the button in a panel and Dock the panel to the bottom of the form (or wherever you want it). You can also use a splitter control and place buttons in one section and content in the other.

Comment: I tried that.
this.options.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top);
this.options.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x - 90, y + 80);
but it doesn't work, the button still moves.

Comment: That's because you've fixed it only to Top. You need to fix it to all the edges relative to which you want the button fixed. Maybe something like button.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);

Comment: I saw your code snippet. The problem here is setting the dock and anchor is meaningless untill windows actually renders the control. I suggest you create both your buttons when the form loads and make one of them invisible instead of removing them from Controls collection. On each of the button click handlers toggle the visibility of both buttons. You can use the button.Visible property.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Anchor` property on the button to `Top, Left` . Then it is always the same length away from the top and left side. This is also a default setting.

Make sure the `Dock` property is set to `None`:

```
        button1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50);
        button1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
```

When you add the button to your form, it is then drawn 50 pixels from the top, and 50 pixels from the left, **according to the control which holds it**. In this case, the form:

```
this.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Are you sure the x and y variables aren't messing up the location?

Comment: i tried changing them to numbers it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Please make yourself clearer: You wrote that you **scroll** the form, right?

**Normal behaviour** is that every control, including all buttons, **will move with** it.

Is that your problem or is there another 'movement' going on?

Since the previous responses didn't help here is a solution for the (somewhat exotic) case of a fixed button:

First create form variable to hold the original Top value:

```
int oldButton1Top;
```

Then set it in the Load event:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //..
   oldButton1Top = button1.Top;
   //
}
```

And then code the Scroll event of the form like this:

```
private void Form1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   button1.Top = oldButton1Top + e.NewValue - e.NewValue;
}
```

This should keep your button fixed at its original position.

BTW: In one answer you were told to set the anchor to true on *opposing* edges. This is will make the button *grow* or *shrink* when the windows resizes and is ceratinly not what you want

Comment: Thank you so much.. I actually fixed it another way, but thanks a lot